# Create organizationalBrandingProperties

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to create Organizational branding via Graph API
Unfortunately it doesn't work as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organizationalbrandingproperties-create?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

```
curl --fail-with-body --silent --show-error --oauth2-bearer TOKEN -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @- https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization/7c9674e7-ad41-482b-af13-fff7ba1c38f6/branding <<< '{
    "backgroundColor":"#FFFF33",
    "signInPageText":"Welcome",
    "usernameHintText":"hint"
}'
{
  'error': {
    'code': 'Request_BadRequest',
    'message': 'Specified HTTP method is not allowed for the request target.',
    'innerError': {
      'date': '2021-04-21T12:59:57',
      'request-id': 'a5ce577c-d0a9-4888-9999-521d7ba452b1',
      'client-request-id': 'a5ce577c-d0a9-4888-9999-521d7ba452b1'
    }
  }
```

neither PATCH works:

```
curl --fail-with-body --silent --show-error --oauth2-bearer TOKEN  -X PATCH -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @- https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization/7c9674e7-ad41-482b-af13-fff7ba1c38f6/branding <<< '{
    "backgroundColor":"#FFFF33",
    "signInPageText":"Welcome",
    "usernameHintText":"hint"
}'
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "Resource '7c9674e7-ad41-482b-af13-fff7ba1c38f6' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-04-21T13:07:43",
      "request-id": "c2c7056b-0043-40cb-82b8-6d262f190005",
      "client-request-id": "c2c7056b-0043-40cb-82b8-6d262f190005"
    }
  }
```

I tried opening an Azure support request but they told me

> The AAD Developer queue is experiencing a very high number of requests.
> Please expect a delay in the assignation as the cases are assigned considering case severity, time in queue, customer service level and business impact.

Since Azure support has proven to be useless yet again, maybe somebody here would be able to help me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test, I have the same error when I use PUT method.

But PATCH works fine for me.

`id` should be the organization id or tenant id.

Please get the `id` first with

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/organization/
```

Then use the `id` for PATCH method:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization/{id}/branding
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Language: en-US
{
    "backgroundColor": "#FFFF33",
    "signInPageText": "Welcome",
    "usernameHintText": "hint"
}
```

---

**Update:**

Application token is not supported for this endpoint. See [Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organizationalbrandingproperties-create?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).

[image]

Comment: I do, and it still fails. The only difference is I use GET https://graph.microsoft.com/1.0/organization/

Comment: `curl --fail-with-body --silent --show-error --oauth2-bearer 'TOKEN' https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization  | jq -r '.value[].id' ` to be exact

Comment: @JakubBochenski What if you use https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?

Comment: Same error, but for some reason the message is missing the uuid `"Resource '' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."` BTW. This is executed against a different organization than my script runs against. I don't have permissions to modify branding on the account I get when I log into explorer.

Comment: Maybe PATH will only work if you set the branding before, manually?

Comment: @JakubBochenski No. I didn't set the branding before manually but I can use PATCH. You should use the same account which you test with CURL script and execute it against the same organization.

Comment: My script is using the same account. Graph explorer is using a different account than the script because that is the only option I have to log in there. What do you mean?

Comment: @JakubBochenski So the 2 accounts are in the same tenant right? Then please use the same organization id while testing in Microsoft Graph explorer.

Comment: I guess "Application token not supported" might be the reason.. why doesn't it respond with Forbidden then? BTW I wasn't notified of your edits to the answer

Comment: @JakubBochenski Some endpoints may not support application token currently but the error message sometimes is not meaningful. I think MS should optimize this. Yeah I updated my answer after you told me that you were using application token. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: Azure Support finally responded with "I did some tests on my end, and I was able to reproduce the same behavior you described on my test environment, and I was also not able to add branding details using Delegated Permissions and a user, so I believe the issue is probably more deep than the type of permissions only."

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft support finally responded (after 2 months!) with

> Application Permission are currently not supported on this
> endpoint, meaning that you will need an on-behalf of user token with
> Delegated permissions to use this endpoint.
>
> Since your goal was to automate this process, one workaround that
> sometimes is feasible is to have a dedicated user in your tenant to
> perform those actions, and that will authenticate with ROPC flow. This
> flow allows to directly send the credentials information (username and
> password) and because of that does not require an UI or interaction.
>
> There is currently a known issue regarding the GET and PATCH method for the branding endpoint that is already reported and the fix
> is in progress. This issue will cause an 404 error mentioning that the
> tenant resource is not found.
>
> Issue seems to be with locale being used, If you wish to get/update
> the default branding, can you please try to include an header with
> Accept-language as 0 (shown in the below image), if you want to get
> branding for any other locale, you’ll need to pass the valid ISO-639
> locale.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Graph API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organizationalbranding-update?view=graph-rest-1.0), organisation branding can be retrieved and *updated* via the API. There is no mention of *creating* the initial branding.

I tested with a new tenant and a `PATCH /organization/{organizationId}/branding` request fails for new tenants, but is successful if the initial configuration of the company branding has been done manually first.

FYI, this was tested using a Service Principal (i.e. Application permission type), which avoids having to rely on delegations.

I hope that helps.